# Distinct results in one column

Tags: distinct

Newbie here.  This is an old question that seems to have no concensus.  The following query returns the information I want, but I'd like rows to have a distinct 'case_price'

```
SELECT case_price,size,style,piece_weight,color,unique_key 
FROM products 
WHERE style='$shirt_id' AND color='$shirtcolor' 
ORDER BY unique_key,piece_weight
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct case_price,size,style,piece_weight,color,unique_key 
FROM products 
WHERE style='$shirt_id' AND color='$shirtcolor' 
ORDER BY unique_key,piece_weight
```